# Loading in C doesn't come out right

Tags: c

Below is my simple code, in which I am trying to make a loading animation, but the output seems to be unrelated to what is expected. Please assist me in pointing out my mistakes, as I am new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LO();
main(){
    LO();
}

LO(){
    char ad = '-';
    int n   = 1;
    while (n<10){
        printf(" %c >", ad);
        Sleep(1000);
        ad += n*'-';
        n++;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
 - > Z > ┤ > ; > ∩ > ╨ > ▐ >  > ü >
```

What I expected:

->

*then clear screen*

-->

*then clear screen*

--->

and more till a certain times.

*then clear screen*

Comment: A `char` in C is a single character.

Comment: So am i supposed to put 


`char ad[20] = '-';`

?

Comment: String handling in C is complicated and you need to read a book or take a class. In this case you don't actually need to create a string, but can just print `-` in a loop.

Comment: It's worth noting that nothing in this code will clear the 'screen'. To do that you'll either need to use [Ansi escape codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) or [native manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) (The docs are wrong now, new windows patches do support ANSI escape sequences).

Answer (score 3):

**C** is *not* Python. It does not have `n *` string concatenation.

This line:

```
ad += n*'-';
```

ad has a numeric ASCII value of 45 at first. The literal '-' is also 45. You expect that you concatenate n * '-' to the string but you are just doing numeric calculations.

So when `n == 1` you add 45 to 45 which is ASCII 'Z', and that's what you see in your output.

When you want to concatenate in C you use `strcpy`, `strcat`.

A rather hacky way to do this would be the %.*s format specifier for printf.

```
const char *fullline = "---------------------------------";
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%.*s\n", i, fullline);
```

printf cuts off fullline after i characters.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a `for` loop:

```
void LO(void)
{
    int n = 1;

    while(n < 10)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("-");
        printf(">");

        Sleep(1000);

        printf("\r");
        fflush(stdout);

        n++;
    }
}
```